What causes this involution behaviour on the Markov tree?
I stumbled upon an unexpected behavior of the Markov tree, and wonder if it is a specific property of said Markov tree, or whether it is something more general. I am sadly restricted to the part of the late Martin Aigner's book https://archive.org/details/markovstheorem100000aign/page/n275/mode/2up that is publicly available, and did not find any hints so far. How to prove the conjecture (see below) is beyond me.
Does something similar happen with Fairy fractions? (cfr. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.07155)
Definitions:
The Markov tree can be defined as a binary tree $M(r,c)$ of triples $\{u,v,w\}$ with apex $M(0,0) = \{1,5,2\}$, satisfying $u^2 +v^2 +w^2 = 3 u v w$, where row $r$ contains $2^r$ column entries $M(r,0) .. M(r, 2^r-1)$.
Each triple $\{u,v,w\}$ at $M(r,c)$ produces 2 descendants in row $r+1$ :
$M(r+1, 2c ) = \{u,3 u v -w, v\}$ and $M(r+1, 2c +1) = \{v, 3 v w - u, w\}$.
Modular:
Restricting the Markov tree entries to their residues modulus prime $p$, $(p\gt 3)$ limits the count of allowed triples to $p(p+3)$ or $p(p-3)$ depending on
$p\equiv1$ or $p\equiv3\pmod4$. A relation also exists for the count of allowed triples for composite modulus.
Path:
any entry in the Markov tree below the apex is uniquely defined by its binary path from the apex, coding a left branching as $0$ (and a right branching as $1$).
The path to $M(r,c)$ is then equal to $c$ written in binary with $r$ bits. Conversely, any binary string can be interpreted as a unique address to an entry in the Markov tree.
Cycles:
Any repeating binary string of length $r$ on the modular Markov tree must produce a cycle: the number of different triples is limited,
and when the starting triple gets visited a second time after $k\,r$ steps, the sequence repeats with cycle length $k$. So $k \le p(p\pm3)$.
Eigencycles:
each entry $M(r,c)$ defines an infinite repeating binary string by concatenating copies of its own address path.
This defines a different cycle length $k$ for each modulus $p$.
Pairing: (conjecture)
each entry $M(r,c)$ is paired with an entry $M(r,c')$ by the relation that the eigencycle of $M(r,c)$ has the same length as that of $M(r,c')$ for any modulus $p$ (prime or not).
This relation is an involution $c\iff c'$ on the binary strings of their address paths.
The involution has $2^{(r+1)/2}$ fixed points if $r$ is odd and $2^{(r+2)/2}$ if $r$ is even. (A233411 in OEIS counts the number of pairs). That leaves a majority of the $2^r$ entries paired for $r \gt5$.
Involution:
The involution above on binary strings is:
for $c$ odd : rotate right one place, then reverse ;
for $c$ even:
if $c\equiv0$ or $2 \pmod8$, rotate right $3$ places, then reverse ;
if $c\equiv4$ or $6 \pmod8$, rotate right $3$ places, then reverse and complement ;
Since the involution is independent of the chosen modulus, maybe it can be considered as an inherent property of the Markov tree.
The above conjecture has been tested up to row $11$ and for the first $50$ primes. (Counter examples welcome).

Apeirogonal Tiling.
The Markov tree with apex $\{1,5,2\}$ can be considered as one of 6 branches of an infinite net as shown in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-3_apeirogonal_tiling.
On this (hyperbolic) tiling, select a center 'X' around which the apeirogons get labeled $1$.
Apply the Markov equation $u^2+v^2+w^2 = 3\, u\,v\,w$ to find the new labels joining 2 already labeled apeirogons: the largest root of the quadratic $w^2 - (3\,u\,v)\,w + (u^2+v^2) = 0$.
The original Markov tree, with apex where apeirogons $1$, $5$ and $2$ meet, now occurs 6 times, among which 3 mirrored copies.
Standard Node labeling.
A node surrounded by apeirogons with (anti-clockwise) labels $A$, $B$, $C$ will be labeled $\{A,B,C\}$ when reached from the $AC$ edge, but as $\{B,C,A\}$ when reached from the $AB$ edge (and $\{C,A,B\}$ when reached from the $BC$ edge).
Define a standard flow direction moving away from X (the unique source). This results in a standard labeling for every node.
Path extension.
An infinite cyclic path starting at the $\{1,5,2\}$ apex, consisting of a set of binary choices, can be uniquely reversed. This results in a path that is infinite in both directions. The path "starting at $\{1,5,2\}$" actually means "a path along the edge between the $1$ and $2$ apeirogons towards the node where $1$, $2$ and $5$ apeirogons meet, and at that node, walk right or left according to the first binary instruction".
Its reverse is "a path along the edge between the $1$ and $2$ apeirogons away from the node where $1$, $2$ and $5$ apeirogons meet, and at the first node reached, walk right or left according to the first binary instruction".
The reverse path is the concatenation of the complement of the reverse cycle.
Path dependent Node labeling.
Tracing a path against the standard flow direction will permute (rotate) the elements in the triples.
In the forward direction a node $\{u,v,w\}$ will produce
$\{x,y,z\} = \{u,3\,u\,v-w,v\}$ on instruction 0 (walk right to left child) and
$\{x,y,z\} = \{v,3\,v\,w-u,w\}$ on instruction 1 (walk left to right child).
The reverse operation is
$\{u,v,w\} = \{x,z,3\,x\,z-y\}$ to undo instruction 0 and
$\{u,v,w\} = \{3\,x\,z-y,x,z\}$ to undo instruction 1.
Undoing forward instruction 0 equals backward instruction 1 and vice versa.
Back travel.
If the last bit of the cycle is $1$, then the (complemented) reverse path will turn right at $\{1,2,1\}$ and reach $\{2,5,1\}$. This is a mirror version of the original, and so undoes the complementing. The path from there on will be similar to the original, but $1$ step further into the cycle. The labeling of the nodes will however be permuted.
If the last bit of the cycle is $0$, then the (complemented) reverse path will turn left at $\{1,2,1\}$ and reach $\{1,1,1\}$. A second step will reach (a different) $\{1,2,1\}$.
If the third step turns left, then we again land in a mirrored tree, and again the complementing operation will be undone. The position in the cycle is $3$ steps further.
If the third step turns right, then we land in a 'normal' tree, $3$ steps into the cycle, and the complementing remains in effect.
These three cases correspond to the three choices made in the definition of the involution in question.
Relation between eigencycles $M(r,c)$ and $M(r,c')$
For an eigencycle of length $k\,r$,
if $c \equiv 1 \pmod 2$ then node $n$ of cycle $M(r,c)$ equals node $k\,r-n-2$ of $M(r,c')$ with labeling permuted by $132$ if node $n+1$ of cycle $M(r,c)$ is reached by $0$ (turn right) and by $213$ otherwise.
if $c \equiv 0$ or $2 \pmod 8$ then node $n$ of cycle $M(r,c)$ equals node $k\,r-n-4$ of cycle $M(r,c')$ with labeling permuted by $132$ if node $n+1$ of cycle $M(r,c)$ is reached by $0$ (turn right) and by $213$ otherwise.
if $c \equiv 4$ or $6 \pmod 8$ then node $n$ of cycle $M(r,c)$ equals node $k\,r-n-4$ of cycle $M(r,c')$ with labeling permuted by $312$ if node $n+1$ of cycle $M(r,c)$ is reached by $0$ (turn right) and by $231$ otherwise.

Should have mentioned the idea of 'tracing back' was suggested by William Orrick, who helped formulate and correct this reply by private email. All defects in the above are however purely mine.
